# Open folder listing in right pane of Windows Explorer without pressing Enter

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Apologies for an obviously stupid question, but I have a problem with Windows 10 explorer I could not find a solution for myself.

When I'm keyboard-navigating the file structure in the left pane of the explorer, the content of folders I go to does not get shown in the right pane. If I want to see it while my cursor is on a particular folder in the left pane, I have to specifically press Enter. Then the content is shown on the right. Otherwise the previous folder listing remains there until I press Enter next time.

Can I force Windows 10 to do that just as it was possible in Windows XP?

Many thanks!

Comment: God I miss that feature in XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no resolution to this in Windows, unless you switch to a 3rd party application like Total Commander.

However, it's been almost 2 years since the question, and the world moved on with me taking a plunge and moving completely away from Windows based office setup to Linux. Lots and lots of pain in the first year as the learning curve is very steep, but in the end it's well worth it.

The Linux ecosystem offers great applications for keyboard-centric users like myself. Choices of open source and free apps are mind boggling, I for that matter settled on a single application Krusader which is a superior file manager to anything I saw before under Windows.

Also, there's no downside to dropping Windows as the base OS, as if I need to use MS Office applications (Excel, Word etc) for clients' documents/projects I just start a VM which loads in under 10 seconds. I set up the VM without access to internet, so really I do not need even to update Windows/MS cr*p anyway.

I'm really glad I did this as flexibility and power of Linux is jaw dropping.